Unity relay multiplayer being same client even with different client Login inputs
I have a multiplayer game with Unity Relay and logging in with Unity Authentication. I am logging in with two different player credentials. But when I log in and create a host and join that host from another Unity instance cloned with parrelsync, I see that both has same client ID. One is not being treated as a different player. Also checked with build and run but client IDs are being same (0). What can I do to remedy this and test two different palyers on same machine?


I guess the login is device wide probably ... According to this did you try the Multiplayer Playmode Package
